# Chrome extension - How to focus a field form to the current page only with name field not id

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to write in one fields of form which has of ID but only no name.
Fields is on the web page which displays at present in the sailor(browser).

Comment: Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) : `document.querySelector('[name="yourName"]').focus()`

Comment: I have an error message in the console of log. Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-WfO9wSBkvh8spbMC2BnVAyVv0hhmJ0sHZm6c0Dpr2LI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery you can use

```
$("input[name='focusme'").focus();
```

You can also use

```
document.querySelector('[name="focusme"]').focus() ;
```

Comment: I have an error message in the console of log.

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-WfO9wSBkvh8spbMC2BnVAyVv0hhmJ0sHZm6c0Dpr2LI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.